# Yet another ASP.NET MVC Route not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to write tests for an MVC 3 route and am still not getting a match. Why would this not work in tests? I'm going off http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx and from looking at the MVC code it might have something to do with the VirtualPathProvider?

Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "import_DownloadTemplate",
        "{culture}/Client/{clientId}/DownloadTemplate",
        new { controller = "Import", action = "DownloadTemplate" },
        new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") });
}
```

ImportController

```
[HttpGet]
[Cache(Order = 1)]
[OutputCache(Order = 2, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult DownloadTemplate(string culture, long clientId)
{
    byte[] result = this.repository.GetTemplateByClientId(clientId, culture);

    return new FileContentResult(result, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Test using MOQ

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRoutes()
    {
        string url = "~/en-us/Client/1/DownloadTemplate";

        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContextMock.Setup(c => c.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)
            .Returns(url);

        RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
        MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);

        var routeData = routes.GetRouteData(httpContextMock.Object);
        // routeData is null!

        Assert.AreEqual("import", routeData.Values["controller"].ToString());
        Assert.AreEqual("DownloadTemplate", routeData.Values["action"].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the HttpMethod, so add these lines in the TestRoutes method:

```
string httpMethod = "GET";
httpContextMock.Setup(c => c.Request.HttpMethod).Returns(httpMethod);
```